# MYSQL: Showing the right records

Tags: html, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to make a forum kind of thing for myself so I can learn from it. Now I need it to only show the 'topics' from a board with the right `board_id` as you can see on the first picture that are the boards and the second picture is the database with the topics so if I click on 'Nieuws & Events' board it only needs to show me the record with the topicnaam(topicname) = salespage.

I am only strugling to get this and I am not really sure what to do.

Ps. This is my first question so tell me if I am doing something wrong or if I am missing some important information.

**Database with the main `boards`**
[image]

**Database with the forum topics**
[image]

** The code to show the topics:**

```
                <?php


                    $toppic = $app->get_topics();
                    foreach($toppic as $topic){

                        echo '<a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie"> <div id="topic">';
                        echo '<div id="topicimg">';
                        if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
                            echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'].'/'.$topic['foto'].'" />';
                        } else {
                            echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
                        }
                        echo '</div><div id="topictekst">';
                        echo '<b>'.$topic['topicnaam'].'</b>'; 
                        echo ' - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . " " . $topic['achternaam'] ;
                        echo '<span style="float:right; margin-top:15px; margin-left:5px;">reacties</span> <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
                        echo '<hr><span class="badge bg-red">' . $board['topic'] . '</span>';
                        echo '</div></div></a>';
                    }
                ?>
```

**The functions I am using:**

```
 public function get_boards(){
        $getBoards = $this->database->query("SELECT boards.*, ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id FROM boards 
        LEFT JOIN ledenpagina ON ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id = boards.ledenpagina_id
        ORDER BY id DESC");
//        $this->database->bind(":ledenpagina_id", $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id']);
        $boards = $this->database->resultset();

        return $boards;

    }


    public function get_topics(){
        $getTopic = $this->database->query("
        SELECT topics.*, klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM topics 
        LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id=klanten.id
        ORDER BY id ASC");
//        $this->database->bind(":ledenpagina_id", $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id']);
        $topics = $this->database->resultset();

        return $topics;

    }
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Told.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you signed up today, to get a better idea of what types of questions you can ask. It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Join`

Here is an example:

```
SELECT Boards.id, Boards.topic, Topics.board_id, Topics.topicnaam
FROM Boards
INNER JOIN Topics
ON Boards.id=Topics.board_id
WHERE Boards.id = 2;
```

Comment: But is it only showing the right topics for the right boards then?

Comment: @checkingthestring Now it wil take all topics within `board id 2`

Comment: But if I have a lot of board I dont want to make this SQL function for all of them seperate

Comment: @checkingthestring Where do you use your database? In PHP or what?

Comment: I am using PHPMYADMIN and make it in PHP. so I have a different file with only functions from sql.

Comment: @checkthestring Je kunt alle topics in PHP weergeven van een specifieke board door middel van deze code: `SELECT topicnaam FROM topics WHERE board_id = 2` die rows kun je dan in een loop zetten zodat het in een tabel onder elkaar komt. Is dit wat je bedoeld? Je moet wel minimaal 2 verschillende SQL queries gebruiken voor het resultaat dat je wilt.

Comment: wat ik zeg maar wil hebben is dat als ik op een board klik dat hij de juiste topics pakt doormiddel van een functie. alleen als je `WHERE board_id = 2` doet moet je die 2 elke keer aanpassen per board dat je hebt.  maar ik wil zeg maar 1 functie hebben of 2 die het voor alle boards doen

Comment: @checkthestring Als je alle boards laat zien op je pagina kun je een functie maken dat als je op een board klikt die het ID van dat board ophaalt en dan in de topics tabel dat ID invult zodat hij alle topics van dat specifieke board laat zien met 1 functie.

Comment: Heb jij een manier/code hoe dit werkt? Heb me vraag iets aangepast zodat je kan zien hoe ik het nu heb

Comment: @checkthestring Ik wil je graag helpen maar daarvoor moet ik in je code /database zijn om wat uit te proberen. Als je dit zou willen kun je contact met me opnemen via: jarirengeling@outlook.com dat is wat makkelijker communiceren. Als ik het voor je heb gebouwd kan ik je eventuele toelichting geven.

Comment: Ik zal contact opnemen met je. maar even dat je het weet je kan de database en mijn script en functies allemaal nu ook zien in de vraag

Comment: @checkthestring Klopt, maar ik ga niet heel je systeem overnemen zodat ik de functionaliteit kan testen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

If you have in input the board id:

```
SELECT t.* FROM topics t
JOIN boards b
    ON t.borad_id = b.id
WHERE b.id = 2
```

or

```
SELECT t.* FROM topics t
WHERE t.borad_id = 2
```

If you have in input board description:

```
SELECT t.* FROM topics t
JOIN boards b
    ON t.borad_id = b.id
WHERE b.description = 'Nieuws & Events'
```

Comment: Thanks! but is if I am making a lot of boards I need to make this SQL function for all of them seperate is there not a way to check if you click on one that it will check in the db what 'board id' it has

Comment: @checkingthestring: You can redirect your input on SQL query. You must write PHP code (if you use PHP) to build your query with parameters